# How to use Django crispy-forms with generic DetailView

Tags: django, django-templates, django-generic-views, django-crispy-forms

If I define my own views based on my own forms then I can add my crispy-forms helper to the Form class definition.

But if I use `DetailView` from `django.views.generic` I'm not creating a form, I don't even need a `forms.py`, `DetailView` is doing it for me.

In my template I am being passed the object.

I can't get my head around how to access the Form to add the helper and set it's attributes, and how to pass the right thing to my template so that

```
{% crispy form %}
```

will work.

TO clarify, I'm trying to learn how to use Django's generic class based views. Like DefaultView. There is no Form that I am declaring. I create a view as

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

class MyView(DetailView):
    model=MyModel
```

and render it with

```
url(...... ,MyView.as_view()...)
```

My template receives an the model instance as an object. How do I combine that with crispy-forms when I don't have a form?

I know how to create my own form and use `crispy` in my template but I want to use the DRY combination of a generic CBV to save writing unnecessary forms and not do all rhe work that crispy styles for me.

If I create a form then surely I'm replacing the work done by the generic CBV and I have to write all my own response handling. If I understand correctly that's the train for using the generics.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the "get_context_data" method in the detailview to include a form.
You should take into account that DetailView is a  - display - view, so a form doesn't make sense here.
Anyways:
Look at the articles example in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/)

You could do something like:

```
class MyDetailView(DetailView):

model = MyModel

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(MyDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['form'] = MyForm() 
    return context
```

the form won't have any data loaded, so you could use the "initial" keyword

It is a lot of work, so maybe this isn't the right generic view for the job.. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question. I'm trying to learn how to use Django's generic class based views. Like DefaultView. There is no Form that I am declaring. I create a view as

Comment: ... class MyView(DetailView) instance it with a model and render it with MyView.as_view(). My template receives an the model instance as an object. How do I combine that with crispy-forms when I don't have A form?

Comment: DetailView is a display view. You shouldn't use a form. But I will update with a way to pass it to the template

Comment: Essentially I'm trying to learn the best DRY ways to do stuff before I implement a lot more models along with a lot more `admins` `forms` and `views` that take up lots of lines of code looking very similar to each other, needing lots of edits if I change the content of all of them. I want to understand all of the generics to see if I can use them or create my own versions. But I am also using `crispy-forms` for the HTML styling and I don't want to give that up. I was hoping to get `{% crispy %}` to work with a view or get a form that represents the content of a CBV to use `{% crispy form %}`

Comment: maybe it's just not possible to use `crispy-forms` and get the full benefits of the generic `CBVs`

Comment: You can still use Generic CBV UpdateView with crispy-forms, and your form can be styled not to look like a form.